# CSS/HTML - trouble with nested table

Tags: html, css, html-table, nested

Here's my current fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UjAQf/79/

My target table design is this:

[image]

But I'm having some trouble as you can see getting all the nesting correct.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use nesting, use col-span and row-span to make a cell take multiple columns/rows.